# Rpi ILI9341 2.8" 240 x 320 5110 SPI TFT LCD Screen Setup Problem

Tags: gpio, spi, retropie, terminal, lcd

I ordered a cheap 2.8 inch ILI9341 screen from Amazon (https://www.amazon.co.uk/240x320-Screen-Serial-Module-ILI9341/dp/B07MXH92RL/ref=sr_1_12?dchild=1&keywords=spi+screen&qid=1589230039&sr=8-12) in the hopes of using it in a custom handheld Retropie console. However, I have attempted many different methods, none of which seem to work. I have reason to believe that the screen is not faulty as, when I give power to the backlight, it lights up, so I think that this is a software issue. Does anybody know how I can configure it to work? Many thanks, Dominic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108457/discussion-on-question-by-dominic-mcgreevy-rpi-ili9341-2-8-240-x-320-5110-spi-t).